Does study power impact on type 1 error?
Usually it is said that study power associated only with type 2 error, but in several studies 1,2 authors declare that "low power also reduces the likelihood that a statistically significant result reflects a true effect"
I don't quite understand what exactly it means. Authors don't directly tell that power impact on type 1 errors, but it seems that they mean something like this.
So, we have the equation to calculate the positive predictive value (PPV):
PPV = ([1 - β] x R)/([1 - β] x R + α)
I wonder that may be this equation actually useful only if we consider infinite amount of potential studies. Then the probability that finding in one particular study depends on the power of this study.
Because denominator of the equation ([1 - β] x R + α) it seems that this denominator counts all possible findings ([1 - β] x R) plus all false positive findings (α) in all possible to exist studies. So this alpha (α) doesn't tell us that among actual findings of the study ([1 - β] x R) some percent of them (i.e. 0,05) are false, but rather that some percent of findings in all possible to exist studies will be false positive.
Therefore, if we have a study with low power but some statistical significant result we can't conclude that this study has low PPV and we shouldn't consider the results. Rather, if we conduct a meta-analysis, only then we should consider PPV of different studies to calculate their weight and credibility for further interpretation of the data.
So, am I wrong in some of these thoughts?

Possible duplicate, likely related

Let me also rephrase my thought. Is it right to consider PPV as it is used for medical test evaluation? If we have 50 diseased and 50 healthy patients and our test tell that all patients have disease, then PPV = 50 (true positive) / 50 (true positive) + 50 (false positive) = 0,5 that is we have 50% chance to give correct diagnosis. BUT if we only test 1 patient, we can't say by our singe result the probability that it is true.

The same with articles: if we have result only from one study, we can't say probability that this result is true, but if we increase power of all possible studies, then number of true positive results will increase while number of false positive results remains the same and thus we will have more valid results overall (compared to true positive + false positive). Nevertheless, if we have only one study then we shouldn't rely on PPV at all, isn't it?


If you wish to rephrase your thinking, edit the question. 2. To calculate power you must specify a decision rule, which normally includes the selection of a significance level. If you increase power you don't change that type I error rate (per your title), but if you increase power across multiple studies you change the proportion of rejections that are correct rejections by getting more correct rejections.


Also likely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585666/studies-with-small-sample-sizes/

The issue relates to the rate of true positives and false positives. With low power you get fewer of the former and so a larger fraction of significant outcomes are false positives. Note that it is not a larger number of false positives.
Imagine that you run 1000 experiments and test each with a hypothesis test with 100% power and and $\alpha=0.05$. Where 10 of those experiments have a true difference to detect and the null is true in the other 995. You will obtain 10 'true' significant results and an additional 5 (nearly 5) that are false positives. Overall you have 10 out of 15 true positives.
Now run the thought experiments again, still with 10 where the null is false, but with only 50% power. You will get 5 true positives (and 5 false negatives) and you will still get 5 false positives. The overall count will now be 5 true positives out of 10.
If you only pay attention to the 'significant' results then this problem is severe, and it is very important to note that with low power the 'true' positive results tend to exaggerate the size of the true effect. I've written more about it in section 3.1 of this open access chapter: A Reckless Guide to P-values.

The power function impacts the posterior probability of a correct inference

"low power also reduces the likelihood that a statistically significant result reflects a true effect"

Although it is stated somewhat awkwardly, my interpretation is that the authors are referring to the posterior probability that the alternative hypothesis is true (a true effect) conditional on rejecting the null hypothesis (getting a statistically significant result).  Suppose you have a hypothesis test with hypotheses $H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0$ and $H_\text{A}: \theta \in \Theta_\text{A}$ and power function $\beta$.  The power function is defined by:
$$\beta(\theta) = \mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0|\theta).$$
Assuming some prior density $\pi$ for the unknown parameter, and applying Bayes theorem gives the posterior probability (taken here to depend on $\beta)$ of a correct inference:
$$\begin{align}
P(\beta)
&\equiv \mathbb{P}(H_\text{A}|\text{Reject }H_0,\beta) \\[18pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\theta \in \Theta_\text{A}|\text{Reject }H_0,\beta) \\[14pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0,\theta \in \Theta_\text{A},\beta)}{\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0,\beta)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\int_{\Theta_\text{A}} \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}{\int_\Theta \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
As you can see, the posterior probability of a correct inference in the test is fully determined by the hypotheses, the power function, and the prior distribution of the unknown parameter used in the test.  Now, suppose we compare two power functions $\beta$ and $\beta'$ for the same test, where $\beta'$ has lower power against the true effect but the same power for null values.  This means that:
$$\begin{matrix}
\beta'(\theta) = \beta(\theta) & & & \text{for } \theta \in \Theta_0, \ \\[6pt]
\beta'(\theta) < \beta(\theta) & & & \text{for } \theta \in \Theta_\text{A}, \\[6pt]
\end{matrix}$$
so we then have:$^\dagger$
$$\begin{align}
P(\beta')
&= \frac{\int_{\Theta_\text{A}} \beta'(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}{\int_{\Theta} \beta'(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta} \\[6pt]
&= \bigg[ 1 + \frac{\int_{\Theta_0} \beta'(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}{\int_{\Theta_\text{A}} \beta'(\theta)\pi(\theta) \ d \theta} \bigg]^{-1} \\[6pt]
&< \bigg[ 1 + \frac{\int_{\Theta_0} \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}{\int_{\Theta_\text{A}} \beta(\theta)\pi(\theta) \ d \theta} \bigg]^{-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\int_{\Theta_\text{A}} \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}{\int_{\Theta} \beta(\theta)\pi(\theta) \ d \theta} \\[14pt]
&= P(\beta). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
This confirms that, ceteris paribus, lowering the power of the test (against the alternative hypothesis) reduces the posterior probability that there is a true effect given that we got a statistically significant result in the test.  This result holds for any prior distribution so long as the prior probability of the alternative hypothesis is non-zero.

$^\dagger$ The strict inequality in this working assumes that the prior probability of the alternative hypothesis is positive (i.e., not zero).

Thank you very much! Unfortunately I am very bad at math, so I can't follow your thought, but nevertheless I guess that we shouldn't judge findings (where p<0,05) of the one particular study based on the power of this study. We can say that if study has low power, may be it didn't find some effects that actually may be there. But if this study has found something, then we shouldn't reject this finding based on the power of this study. Is it correct judgement?

Not really.  What I show here is that the quoted remark you read is correct --- i.e., low power reduces the likelihood that a statistically significant result reflects a true effect.  So a low power actually could be a good reason to be sceptical of "finding something".

The quote from the OP ("low power also reduces the likelihood that a statistically significant result reflects a true effect") is correct, but has nothing to do with PPV. However, the PPV is also negatively affected by the power of the test (or tests). And that 2nd point does not seem to be addressed by the previous answers. I will try to unwrap both points.
Imagine a thought experiment where you run (or simulate) 1000 2-sample t-tests, with both samples from $N(0,1)$, of size say 20. In this case the null is true, that is, the effect is 0. And you run these tests at the "traditional" $\alpha=.05$ level. In this case your power will be $5%$. You will observe about 50 significant results (which are all false positives, or $\alpha$ $errors$. The effects (observed differences) in all these tests will be much larger than 0 (or else they would not have been significant). That is, your significant results all came from "extreme" (non representative) samples.
Now, let's repeat the same experiment, now getting the samples from $X~N(0.001,1)$ and $Y~N(0,1)$; the null is now false, but your power will just be barely above 5%. You will observe, say, 55 significant results. But just as before, for all of these, the effect (observed difference) will be much greater than .001 (as your test is grossly underpowered for such a small effect). The only samples giving you a significant effect afre again extremes, with a much larger observed effect.
Now let's repeat again, but with $X~N(100,1)$ and $Y~N(0,1)$. The null is still false, but now you have 100% power. Pretty much all 1000 tests will be significant. And now, for the vast majority of the significant tests, the effect will be around 100 (you may perhaps find a few tests where the observed effect is, say 50, as your test is very well powered, but this will be very rare).
This is what the authors were alluding to; significant tests in underpowered studies will demonstrate an effect which is significantly larger than the true population effect. One can see this CV post for additional discussions. This is one of the reasons why reporting post-hoc power, or effect, is meaningless; they are both deterministically related to the p-value, as shown in this CV post. This is also a contributor to the "reproducibility crisis"; if I ever get a significant result from an underpowered study, I will eagerly publish it, and gleefully note the "important" effect I found. My colleague will try to reproduce it, with a similar sample size, and will fail to get a significant result (or will try to reproduce it with a much larger sample size, and will get a significant result, but a much smaller effect). In both cases, my initial bubble has burst.
Now, does low power also affect the PPV? Yes, with different angles to consider.
The first, obvious one, goes back to the very definition of the PPV. $PPV=\frac {TP} {TP+FP}=\frac {1} {1+\frac {FP} {TP}}$. If the power gets lower, all other things being equal, then $TP$ will be lower, and so the denominator will be greater, and the PPV will be less.
The above was related to the PPV of a single (dichotomous) test. There is a 2nd approach (the one in the OP's question, as pointed to by the 2 sources linked, including by Iaonidis in his (in?)famous paper "Why most published research findings are false"). This is related to the PPV of a "family" of related (non dichoptomous) hypothesis tests. This is a touchy subject, because many statisticians object to the introduction of what is basically a Bayesian prior into what is otherwise a purely frequentist approach to significance testing. But I will leave the controversy aside, and take Ioanidis approach as a given.
Slightly re-arranging the equation in the OP's question, we have $PPV=\frac {power} {power + \frac {\alpha} {R}}$. The graph for PPV, as a function of power would look, for $R=.5$,$\alpha=.05$ like this

So yes, that PPV goes down as the power goes down. On this very topic, you may also be interested in the following post. It has a nice discussion, and some interesting examples, about p-values, PPV, etc.
This (lower PPV with lower power) is yet another contributor to the reproducibility crisis. So we have exaggerated effects (the sentence quoted by the OP), and we also have larger proportions of false positives (hence lower PPV), when power gets lower (the 2 papers linked by the OP). But the 2 are 2 different phenomena.

I have skimmed the post linked at the end of your answer and I saw nothing about p-values per se. As far as I can see—admittedly without spending time to read closely—that post is about hypothesis tests where every outcome is a dichotomous accept/reject on the basis of p<$\alpha$, with $\alpha=0.05$ throughout. Thus it ignores the evidential meaning of p-values entirely.

@MichaelLew, I do not dispute your reading of the post at all. It is indeed treating NHST as a dichotomous test of the basis of $p<\alpha$. And whether the title of the post is truly descriptive of its content is also debatable. But the content of the post is exactly the point of the OP's 2 linked papers (including Ioanidis's one), and the focus of the OP's question, wrt PPV. So my comment on relevance was wrt the OP's question.
